# GCP: Allow Service Account to Impersonate a User Account with Google Analytics Scopes

Tags: python, google-analytics-api, google-workspace, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

I am trying to create a script that enables a Service Account `ga@googleanalytics.iam.gserviceaccount.com` to impersonate a user account `ga@domain.tld` with the following GA scopes:

```
target_scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.manage.users',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.provision',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.user.deletion']
```

So it can add properties to other GA accounts that the user account (ga@domain.tld) has previously been given access to.

This is the code I've written that **includes impersonation**:

```
from google.auth import impersonated_credentials    
from google.oauth2 import service_account
target_scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.manage.users','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.provision','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.user.deletion']

source_credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(    
'ga-1234567890.json',    
scopes=target_scopes)    
target_credentials = impersonated_credentials.Credentials(
source_credentials=source_credentials,
    target_principal='ga@domain.tld',    
target_scopes=target_scopes,    
lifetime=500)
   

client = AnalyticsAdminServiceClient(credentials=target_credentials)
```

Which returns the exception:

```
>Oops! <class 'google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable'> occurred.
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:    
status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE    
details = "Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: ('Unable to acquire impersonated credentials', '{\n  "error": {\n"code": 404,\n"message": "Not found; Gaia id not found for email ga@domain.tld",\n     
"status": "NOT_FOUND"\n  }\n}\n')"

debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer analyticsadmin.googleapis.com:443 {created_time:"2022-11-17T15:28:49.7504959+00:00", grpc_status:14, grpc_message:"Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: (\'Unable to acquire impersonated credentials\', \'{\\n  \"error\": {\\n\"code\": 404,\\n\"message\": \"Not found; Gaia id not found for email ga@domain.tld\",\\n\"status\": \"NOT_FOUND\"\\n  }\\n}\\n\')"}"
```

When I attempt to run the below code **without impersonation**:

```
from google.auth import impersonated_credentials    
from google.oauth2 import service_account    
target_scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.manage.users','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.provision','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.user.deletion']

source_credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(    
'ga-1234567890.json',    
scopes=target_scopes)    

client = AnalyticsAdminServiceClient(credentials=source_credentials)
```

It returns the exception:

> Oops! <class 'google.api_core.exceptions.Unauthenticated'> occurred.
> grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
> status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
> details = "Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: ('Unable to acquire impersonated credentials', '{\n  "error": {\n"code": 404,\n"message": "Not found; Gaia id not found for email ga@domain.tld",\n
> "status": "NOT_FOUND"\n  }\n}\n')"
> debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer analyticsadmin.googleapis.com:443 {created_time:"2022-11-17T15:28:49.7504959+00:00", grpc_status:14, grpc_message:"Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: ('Unable to acquire impersonated credentials', '{\n  "error": {\n"code": 404,\n"message": "Not found; Gaia id not found for email ga@domain.tld",\n"status": "NOT_FOUND"\n  }\n}\n')"}"

The service account `ga@googleanalytics.iam.gserviceaccount.com` has principal `ga@domain.tld` with roles `Service Account Token Creator` and `Service Account User`

The service account `ga@googleanalytics.iam.gserviceaccount.com` has Domain-wide Delegation configured in Google Workspace Admin with scopes

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.manage.users
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.provision
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.user.deletion

Not sure what I am missing here, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code blocks would be easier to read if you start them with `\`\`\`python` and end them with `\`\`\``

Comment: The [documentation](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/master/reference/google.oauth2.service_account.html#domain-wide-delegation) uses `subject` for the user identity being delegated on `service_account.Credentials` **or** you can set it after creation with `credentials.with_subject(subject)`. Have you tried that approach?

Comment: I haven't tried that. How would I write it? Something like this?

target_scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']

subject = 'ga@domain.tld'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    'ga-1234567890.json')

scoped_credentials = credentials.with_scopes(target_scopes)
delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject(subject)

client = AnalyticsAdminServiceClient(credentials=target_credentials)

Comment: `target_scopes` would be unchanged.

Comment: `credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('ga-1234567890.json', scopes=target_scopes, subject='ga@domain.tld')`

Comment: I'm assuming (!) that you're using `ga@domain.tld` by way of example and this is not the actual value.

Comment: @DazWilkin that did the trick! Defining the subject was key here, thank you so much. You can post your answer if you'd like.

Comment: Looks like @DaImTo posted an Answer that matches my explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you configured domain wide delegation to the service account though your google workspace.  And configured it to a user who has access to the google analytics account.

The same code used to delegate to the other apis should work as well.

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('my_json.json', scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords'])

delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject("user@yourdomain.com")

client = AnalyticsAdminServiceClient(credentials=delegated_credentials)
```

Now by the looks of your error messages im wondering if the system even supports it.

Im going to send an email off to the team, before we start chasing this lets check delegation is supported.