# setSubject for GA4 PHP API to allow access to all Admin's accounts properties

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-analytics

I'm at an agency with hundreds of client Analytics accounts, and we're of course in the process of converting all our clients to GA4. I'm trying to move our reporting and account management scripts to the new GA4 API https://github.com/googleapis/php-analytics-admin

In our UA management script we can do the following:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('path-to-config.json');
$client->setSubject('admin-user-with-access-to-all-analytics@gmail.com');
```

This works in the old lib. The service account has domain-wide delegated access to the admin user's GA accounts and the API can list all available GA properties.

In the new PHP lib for GA4, you set the config path in the .env file but there doesn't seem to be any way to set the Subject. As it stand the client will only lists accounts to the handful of GA accounts we have manually added the Service Account email to. It would be impractical to do that manually for 100s of accounts.

There's a similar question on SO for the Python library. The user seemed to find a way to do this. But searching to through the PHP lib I don't see any of these equivalent configurations available. Anyone had luck with this? I know this is still in Beta so maybe it will be added eventually?
[GCP: Allow Service Account to Impersonate a User Account with Google Analytics Scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74479630/gcp-allow-service-account-to-impersonate-a-user-account-with-google-analytics-s)

**ANSWER thx to John Hanley**

```
use Google\Analytics\Admin\V1beta\AnalyticsAdminServiceClient; 
use Google\Auth\Credentials\ServiceAccountCredentials; 
$creds = new ServiceAccountCredentials('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly','path/to/json-key.json','ga4-admin-email@gmail.com'); 
$client = new AnalyticsAdminServiceClient(['credentials' => $creds]);
```

Comment: The class that handles impersonation is [here](https://googleapis.github.io/google-auth-library-php/main/Google/Auth/Credentials/ServiceAccountCredentials.html). I do not know how to pass those credentials to the Google Analytics client. On that page search for `domain wide access` to find the section.

Comment: @JohnHanley yes, bless you that did the trick. Thanks for digging that up. For reference it's easy to implement once you set up the ServiceAccountCredentials


`use Google\Analytics\Admin\V1beta\AnalyticsAdminServiceClient;`
`use Google\Auth\Credentials\ServiceAccountCredentials;`

`$creds = new ServiceAccountCredentials('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly','path/to/json-key.json'),'ga4-admin-email@gmail.com');`
`$client = new AnalyticsAdminServiceClient(['credentials' => $creds]);`

Comment: Please post an answer with your new code to benefit everyone and so I can vote for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSWER thx to John Hanley

```
use Google\Analytics\Admin\V1beta\AnalyticsAdminServiceClient; 
use Google\Auth\Credentials\ServiceAccountCredentials; 
$creds = new ServiceAccountCredentials('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly','path/to/json-key.json','ga4-admin-email@gmail.com'); 
$client = new AnalyticsAdminServiceClient(['credentials' => $creds]);
```